# Use image as background of custom shape Card/Material widget

Tags: android, flutter, material-design, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

There is a `ContinuousRectangleBorder` paint which I can pass to the shape parameter of `Card` or `Material` widget.

```
Material(
  shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
  ),
  elevation: 4,
  color: theme.primaryColor,
  child: image,
  borderOnForeground: true,
)
```

But in android if I pass an image to the widget, the image won't clip as the parent.
What is the best way to crop image with the identical shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android create a `CustomClipper` class:

```
class ImageContinuousClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return ContinuousRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200 * 0.625))
        .getOuterPath(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

In general, you can do this:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 200,
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1,
            child: Card(
              shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200 * 0.625),
              ),
              child:Image.network(
                  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2853198/pexels-photo-2853198.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

try this :

```
 Material(
  shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
  ),
  elevation: 4,
  color: theme.primaryColor,
  child: image,
  borderOnForeground: true,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
)
```